# How do I open a file in another window in VIM through the terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

Say I want to open the file "main.cpp".  I have my linux terminal open in the correct directory.  Normally, I just type "vi main.cpp", but this opens the file in the shell window.  How do I open the file in another window?

Comment: What do you mean by another window? Do you want to open in gvim or another terminal window?

Comment: `gnome-terminal -e "vi /etc/passwd"` opens vi in a new gnome-terminal window ([read more](http://askubuntu.com/a/46630)).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using two steps:

1. `:vs` (vertical split) or `:split` (horizontal split)
2. `:open` (path to filename)

Comment: and then use ^w [hjkl] to navigate between the various vim windows.

Comment: That's not a new window

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. I try to answer nevertheless:

`:help client-server`

Thus, you create a server instance:

`vim --servername foo`

Afterwards you can open files in that instance from any shell via:

`vim --servername foo --remote file1 file2`

Or even shorter:

`vim --servername vim` and `vim --remote file1` (the server name 'vim' is assumed here implicitely).

EDIT: Your Vim needs to have support for the client-server architecture:

`:echo has('clientserver')` should result in '1'.

Answer (score 0):

vi is a terminal text editor. It will open in the terminal window it is called from. If you wanted an X based editor, like gVIM, then you are using the wrong editor.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `gvim main.cpp` which will fire up vim in its own GUI which technically will do what you're asking here.